# Why does the web page reload periodically?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am newbie to nextjs.
I have no idea why my website will reload periodically?
I know that hot code loading is the feature of nextjs.
Next.js reloads the page when it detects any change saved to disk.
However, How can I know what is the changes which cause the page reloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fast refresh](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh) is triggered in development mode for a number of reasons like when an error is fixed, a file is updated, or Next detected out of date state.  When stuff is out of sync Next will reload, this sometimes occurs between saves.  The link as a complete list of reasons fast refresh is triggered and more detailed explanation.

You can also [manually force](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh#tips) a page to fast refresh which is helpful when working with code that is invoked on mount.

I have not seen a way to tell what triggered the fast refresh other than an obvious error that was fixed or when a file is updated and saved.